# How to delete whole line from text file, if any specific or more words exists in line

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a text file and I am storing data to that file. Each word is separated by '-'

> word1-word2-word3-word4.

Moreover, I am using DataGridView(control) to display each word in a separate column.

I want to remove specific line from text file where lets say 'word1' and 'word2' match to the given variables

> public static string word1;
>     public static string word2;`

I am trying to implement below code but not getting proper solution to do that. please help. I am newbie to C#...

```
 public static string word1; //static to access in another form
 public static string word2;
 if (e.ColumnIndex == 5) //view
 {
     string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"info.txt");

     word1 = dataGridViewF.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
     word2= dataGridViewF.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

     string[] newLines = lines.Where(line => !line.Contains(word1));

     using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"info.txt", true))
     {
         File.WriteAllLines(@"info.txt"", newLines);
     }
 }
```

Comment: please could you provide us with your output right now?

Comment: Write a method that takes a string and Splits on ‘-‘. Check the two indices to make sure it’s a match. Return true if it’s a match, false if it’s not. Then just use LINQs Where() method to filter the items out when writing to the file

Comment: As a side note, consider how your scheme will behave when someone with a Hyphenated-Last-Name signs up; and is your validator ensuring that phone numbers don't contain dashes? TL;DR - Consider a more robust storage format like [JSON](https://www.json.org/) or [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).

Comment: Should probably store this as Json

Comment: What exactly are your problems? The code in your question will not compile. Please specify any errors, as edit to your question

Comment: Like this: `string needle = "-" + theName + "-"; var filtered = lines.Where(x => !x.Contains(needle)).ToList();`

Comment: You got my problem and this is what I was looking for. Thank you so much. this was so easy. These two lines worked with charm.

Answer (score 2):

Your example text line:

```
FirstName-LastName-age-MobileNo.
```

Is a big indicator that you are likely using the wrong approach.  If a `-` delimits your data, what happens when a phone number has a `-` in it?  What happens when a nice married person has a `-` in their new last name?  Can you see how this would be problematic?

A better approach (as mentioned in the comments) would be to *serialize* your data into a format designed for this.  I will use Json in my example.

First you should create a class that describes your data:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; } //Really should be storing birthday instead...
}
```

When you serialize this object into json it would look like this:

```
{
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "Age": 42,
    "MobilePhoneNumber": "(123) 456-7890"
}
```

And a list of these will look like:

```
[{
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "Age": 42,
    "MobilePhoneNumber": "(123) 456-7890"
},
{
    "FirstName": "Jane",
    "LastName": "Sanders-Doe",
    "Age": 69,
    "MobilePhoneNumber": "(890) 555-1234"
}]
```

So now your code for getting this data is pretty simple (Ill use Json.NET -- the standard library for this):

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"info.json");
List<Person> persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);
```

Now that you have actual objects to work with, your code is much cleaner and less error prone:

```
string fName = dataGridViewF.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
string lName = dataGridViewF.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

string json = File.ReadAllText("info.json");

//'deserializes' which just means turns JSON into a real object
List<Person> persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(json);

//'persons' is now a list of Persons who's names DONT match
//in other words the names that matched are removed from the output
persons = persons.Where(x => x.FirstName != fName && x.LastName != lName).ToList();

//'serialize' means turns an object into a json string
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(persons);

File.WriteAllText("info.json", json);
```

Note that I made the code a bit verbose so you could understand.  A lot of the above lines can be condensed into less lines.

Comment: wow! This is something I really wanted to know about json. This is really helpful. Thank you. Moreover, I defined a 'remove' button for each line in column 5 and when button is pressed, the specific line should be deleted and rest of lines must be restored in Table. (DataGridView) How would I do this after writing new lines back to file ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to do it providing that you are getting `fName` and `lName` correctly:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"info.txt"); //original file

fName = dataGridViewF.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
lName = dataGridViewF.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

var iter = lines.Where(line => {
    string[] name = line.Split('-');
    string f = name[0];
    string l = name[1];
    if(f.ToLower().Equals(fName.ToLower()))
        if (l.ToLower().Equals(lName.ToLower()))
        {
            return false;
        }
    return true;
});

File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\\newfile.txt", iter.ToArray()); //put them in newfile.txt, don't delete the original one which is info.txt
```

*Piece of advice*: Don't use **-** as a delimiter. Because mobile numbers might contain dashes as well. I suggest you change the delimited to become a comma **,**. However, FirstName and LastName being your first two params, won't affect your case. But in general, you want to use a delimiter that you know for sure it won't exist within your values.

Comment: Yes you are right.I didn't notice it as I was more concerned about how to remove.Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome @Emmy Glad to help!